# Admin site does not change the content after CLI command

Tags: magento2

When I try to modify `system.xml` or add a product attribute, I try to run `setup:upgrade`, `cache:flush` or `setup:di:compile`. Why might the Magento admin site still not reflect the change in content that I already added?

Answer (score 0):

Do try these and check on incognito

```
rm -rf pub/static/*
rm -rf generated/*
rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/*
rm -rf var/cache/*
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: It still not working but thank for your help

Comment: Could you check for any exceptions/errors in /var/log and let us know ? also silly question: are you editing and running all your commands on the same project root ? I occasionally do this mistake :D

Comment: Well, it realy hard for me to tell you what my problem is but i can only say that my magento project has a bizarre problem that when i run the command line, my site does not change at all, i check on google and nobody has this issue before. So i hope you can understand it.

Answer (score 0):

If you add attribut to product you probably need to reindex your catalog data

php bin/magento i:rei

you can also try to force the update of the attribut :

php bin/magento queue:consumers:start product_action_attribute.update

What kind of change do you want to make?

Answer (score 0):

You should try this steps :

```
- rm -rf var/cache/* var/page_cache/* var/generation/*
- sudo chmod -R 777 var/ generated/
- Composer update 
- Restart fpm php
- bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
- If you are doing custom work then you should check the directory path.
```

If you are still facing the same do let me know!